# How can I understand the sqlite query plan?

Tags: sqlite, sql-execution-plan

I executed a query on SQLite and the plan part is

```
0|1|5|SCAN TABLE edges AS e1 (~250000 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SEARCH TABLE dihedral USING AUTOMATIC
COVERING INDEX (TYPE=? AND EDGE=?) (~7 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE bounds USING AUTOMATIC
COVERING INDEX (FACE=? AND EDGE=?) (~7 rows)
```

where the query in WHERE is

```
exists (select dihedral.edge from dihedral where ihedral.type=2 and dihedral.edge=e1.edge) and
exists (select bounds.edge from bounds where bounds.face=f1.face and bounds.edge=e1.edge) and
```

I understand this is not a high effeciency query,Ｉjust want to increase the performance.

This is my guess:

1. There is no subquery flattening, right?
2. The two exist subquery introduce the correlated subquery, and as they are acctually executed as indexed nested loop, right?
3. Read the query, because table dihedral and bounds are independent, both are correlated with the outer edge table, so the computational complexity is `O(n^2)` for no index. However, as there are covering index, the performance should be much better, right? I found on wiki, index has performance of `O(log(N))` even better,so the overall performance should be `O(n*log(N))`, is this right?

Could anyone help me to understand what happened? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does support [subquery flattening](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening), but this it not possible for an EXISTS subquery like here.

The AUTOMATIC shows that the database creates a temporary index just for this query.
This is a strong indication that you should create these indexes permanently:

```
CREATE INDEX dihedral_type_edge ON dihedral(type, edge);
CREATE INDEX bounds_face_edge ON bounds(face, edge);
```

The outer query goes through all `edge` rows, and for each row, searches in the indexes.
This would result in `O(edge * (log(dihedral) + log(bounds)))`.
The temporary index creation requires sorting these tables, so the entire runtime ends up being `O(dihedral*log(dihedral) + bounds*log(bounds) + edge*(log(dihedral)+log(bounds)))`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear. In my example, there is another clause `0|0|0|SCAN TABLE faces AS f1 (~500000 rows)    0|1|5|SCAN TABLE edges AS e1 (~250000 rows)   3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE bounds USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (FACE=? AND EDGE=?) (~7 rows)` How to estimate it's order?